# Проблема с переходом между роутами (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-router

Компонент Start отображается нормально, компонент About не весь, только некоторые элементы, компонент Page просто белый фон. Как сделать, чтобы отображалось нормально? До добавления компонеyта Page все работало.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Start } from './components/Start'
import { About } from './components/About '
import { Page} from './components/Page'

function App() {

  return (
   <div className="App">
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<Start/>}/>
       <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
       <Route path="/page" element={<Page/>}/>
     </Routes>
   </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
function Start() {

  return (
   <div>
     1
   </div>
  )
}

export default Start
```

```
function About() {

  let one: any = document.getElementById("one")  

  useEffect(() => {
    one= document.getElementById("one")
  }, [])

  return (
   <div>
     <div id="one">1<div>
     <Link><div id="two">2<div></Link>
   </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

```
function Page() {
  return (
   <div>
     1
   </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте мой написанный код

Ссылка - [https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-help-1-sqx548?file=/src/index.js]